# ASP.Net: After encrypted the web.config "ConnectionString' ,tlide(~) paths showing 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-8.5, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have encrypted the web.config connectionString, then Tilde (~) releted
paths are redirecting to 404 errors,

Ex: ~/ images/ title.png not opening, it showing 404 error,

Please suggest me any IIS settings need to change.

Error screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ev8.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please write it properly. your question seems unclear.

Comment: Did you encrypt the entire Web.config or just the (database) connection string ?
Are your image paths coming from the Database? if so maybe the connection isn't working?
Please show the code that is failing.
Also you have 'ConectioString' misspelled.

Comment: Encrypted URL: aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\project\application"

Comment: Are your image paths coming from the Database? 
Ans: Most of them are static paths.

if so maybe the connection isn't working?  
Ans: ConnectionString working fine login and all working fine.

i'm suspecting IIS server settings misfired, because in another sever it was working fine after encrypted the "ConnectionString".

Comment: Make sure your project structure is correct, enable logs to look for further information... This error is common with incorrect static paths. Do upload an image of project structure with the directory info and/or how you're encrypting it

Comment: Same published code we deployed into another server. But its working fine. I suspecting IIS settings....

Comment: @MPK How you are using these URLs?

Comment: I'm using the URLusing Tlide(~) path. ex: <img src=~/images/title.png/>

Comment: Actually i'm getting error: net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: issued fixed, i have added Bundlemoudle in web.config